# Error: Exceeded maximum number of retries allowed

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

A Firebase project in production that has been working fine for over a year, suddenly starts throwing errors after updating dependencies to latest:

firebase-admin

```
from: ^9.2.0
to: ^11.5.0
```

firebase-functions

```
from: ^3.21.2
to: ^4.2.0
```

Errors like:

```
Error: Exceeded maximum number of retries allowed. at QueryWatch.<anonymous> (/workspace/app/orders/makeOrderDone.function.js:179:27) at QueryWatch.closeStream (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/watch.js:226:18) at /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/watch.js:335:18 at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

and before that error in same log:

```
Error: A backoff operation is already in progress. at QueryWatch.<anonymous> (/workspace/app/orders/makeOrderDone.function.js:169:35) at QueryWatch.closeStream (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/watch.js:226:18) at /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/watch.js:335:18 at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3) at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:9)
```

To give you more context, updating the dependencies was done so I could use the `preferRest` option.

I added a few comments here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/pull/1901

In the time being, I have disabled `preferRest`, but the errors above won't go.

UPDATE:

related code block:

```
db
.collection("Orders")
.doc(orderId)
.collection("Order_Items")
.where("order_status_val", "==", 1)
.onSnapshot(() => {
  // logic and another onSnapshort query nested here
})
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet that is throwing this error? Is it a Firestore query or so and have you tried logging any errors?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I updated the question with a related code block where the error is getting thrown.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. After several hours of usage, snapshot runs into the same exact error and is no longer reacting to changes in firestore.  Which system are you on Omar? I am on Mac, could it be that?

Comment: No, it's unrelated to your system, it's a firestore issue. To fix it, I had to stop using the preferRest option. That's the only solution unfortunately